# Vertical align an img inside a div - My live site differs to JSFiddle? Why?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, jsfiddle

Trying to vertical align an img inside a div. Managed to do it in JSFiddle, but can't get it to work on a live page.

I'm assuming  I've missed something obvious but any help appreciated.

```
.partner_box {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.partner_box img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dvpr_learner/dx7uek55/

Live Page (not working):
http://f4d.co.uk/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try using `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of the transitional doctype you're using now on the Live site, and see if that makes a difference.

---

The Live site seems to be missing a selector that IS present in the Fiddle. Try adding this to your Live page's CSS.

```
.partner_box img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You might wanna check again

Comment: Originally I thought so but that's definitely there. http://f4d.co.uk/test/screen-1.jpg

Comment: Ok, it's there now, but quite sure it wasn't before. However, you might try using `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of the transitional doctype you're using now on the Live site, and see if that makes a difference.